# Remove "more" button from navigation view for custom tab bar with 5+ items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabs

Hello I have created a custom tab bar in swift ui that contains 6 tabs each embedded in a nivation view. When I select the 5th or 6th tabs I see a "more" button at the top. Which is almost like the back button for navigation links. How can I remove this? I tried using navigationbarbackbuttonhidden(true) and that didn't work. I also tried adding .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabbar) onto my tabView and this did not work also. I would appreciate any help to get ride of that button. Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import MapKit

struct MainTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var pop: PopToRoot
    @Namespace var animation

init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
}
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
            NavigationView(){
                FeedView()
            }.tag(1)
            NavigationView(){
                JobsView()
            }.tag(2)
            NavigationView(){
                ExploreView()
            }.tag(3)
            NavigationView(){
                QuestionView()
            }.tag(4)
            NavigationView(){
                MessagesHomeView()
            }.tag(5)
            NavigationStack {
                ProfileView()
            }.tag(6)
        }
        .overlay (
            HStack {
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Home", index: 1, image: selectedTab == 1 ? "h.circle.fill" : "h.circle", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Jobs/Shop", index: 2, image: "", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Explore", index: 3, image: "magnifyingglass", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Ask", index: 4, image: "questionmark", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Messages", index: 5, image: selectedTab == 5 ? "message.fill" : "message", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Profile", index: 6, image: selectedTab == 6 ? "person.crop.circle.fill" : "person.crop.circle", animation: animation)
            }
            , alignment: .bottom
        )
    }
}

struct TabBarButton: View {
    @Binding var change: Int
    var title: String
    var index: Int
    var image: String
    var animation: Namespace.ID
    @EnvironmentObject var popRoot: PopToRoot
    var body: some View{
        Button {
            change = index
            withAnimation {
                popRoot.tab = index
            }
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: image).font(.title2)
                Text(title).font(.system(size: 10))
            }
            .foregroundColor(popRoot.tab == index ? .orange : .primary.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .overlay (
                ZStack {
                    if popRoot.tab == index {
                        TabIndicator()
                            .fill(.orange.gradient)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "TAB", in: animation)
                            .padding(.top, -9)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct TabIndicator: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let newRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y, width: rect.width, height: 3)
        return Path { path in
            path.addRect(newRect)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if you can replace the toolbar (which has the "`More`" button) with an empty view.

First, define a custom extension or view, possibly something like this:

```swift
extension View {
    static var hidden: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Then, since [`navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:)) is deprecated, use [`toolbar(content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-5w0tj) with [`navigationBarLeading`]https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement/navigationbarleading) or [`navigationBarTrailing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement/navigationbartrailing) placement.

```swift
struct MainTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var pop: PopToRoot
    @Namespace var animation

    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
            NavigationView(){
                FeedView()
            }
            .tag(1)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { EmptyView() }
            }

            NavigationView(){
                JobsView()
            }
            .tag(2)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { EmptyView() }
            }

            NavigationView(){
                ExploreView()
            }
            .tag(3)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { EmptyView() }
            }

            NavigationView(){
                QuestionView()
            }
            .tag(4)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { EmptyView() }
            }

            NavigationView(){
                MessagesHomeView()
            }
            .tag(5)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { EmptyView() }
            }

            NavigationStack {
                ProfileView()
            }
            .tag(6)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { EmptyView() }
            }
        }
        .overlay (
            HStack {
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Home", index: 1, image: selectedTab == 1 ? "h.circle.fill" : "h.circle", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Jobs/Shop", index: 2, image: "", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Explore", index: 3, image: "magnifyingglass", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Ask", index: 4, image: "questionmark", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Messages", index: 5, image: selectedTab == 5 ? "message.fill" : "message", animation: animation)
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Profile", index: 6, image: selectedTab == 6 ? "person.crop.circle.fill" : "person.crop.circle", animation: animation)
            }
            , alignment: .bottom
        )
    }
}
```

The `toolbar(content:)` modifier places an `EmptyView()` on the leading position of the navigation bar for each `NavigationView`, which should have the effect of removing the "`More`" button or any other leading items on the navigation bar.

---

> This did not work. I can still see the more button at the top of the screen. Any thoughts?

Another approach would be, since you're already using a custom tab bar UI, to bypass `TabView` for the custom tab bar altogether.

You could hold all the views in an array and show the currently selected one using a conditional statement.
And then use your custom tab bar UI to change the currently selected view.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import MapKit

struct MainTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var pop: PopToRoot
    @Namespace var animation
    
    private var tabs: [AnyView] = [
        AnyView(NavigationView() { FeedView() }),
        AnyView(NavigationView() { JobsView() }),
        AnyView(NavigationView() { ExploreView() }),
        AnyView(NavigationView() { QuestionView() }),
        AnyView(NavigationView() { MessagesHomeView() }),
        AnyView(NavigationStack { ProfileView() })
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if selectedTab < tabs.count {
                tabs[selectedTab]
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                TabBarButton(change: $selectedTab, title: "Home", index: 0, image: selectedTab == 0 ? "h.circle.fill" : "h.circle", animation: animation)
                // Your other TabBarButtons
            }
            .background(Color.white.shadow(radius: 2))
        }
    }
}

// Your other structures
```

This way, you bypass the default behavior of `TabView` and control the view being displayed using your custom tab bar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this did not work. I can still see the more button at the top of the screen. Any thoughts?

Comment: maybe your even an expert with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981945/swift-ui-image-does-not-drag-correctly-when-zoomed-in