# Video reloads instead of pausing WKWebView in Swift

Tags: html, swift, swiftui, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to override YouTube default play and pause button by disabling the YouTube video and putting a clear view above it that is tappable. When the clear view is tapped it changes a binding which decides if the video will play or not (this video autoplays also).

Currently the isVideoPlaying variable does change correctly and the HTML does pick up on the change. The problem now is that I added an event listener of "onclick" this is never executed. I need to change this event listener to on Change of isVideoPlaying.

But I don't know how to do this. The only reason tapping the clear view pauses or plays the video is because when the clear view is tapped swift reloads the whole video which makes it go through the 'onReady' section. This is another issue, I don't want the YouTube video to reload every time the clear view is clicked. I want it to simply play and pause without reloading.

For reference I'm trying to make a Tiktok clone using YouTube shorts.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying)

            Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)//to disable YouTube video
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()
                }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SingleVideoView(link: "-q6-DxWZnlQ")
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1 },
                    events: {
                        'onReady': function(event) {
                            var isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false");
                            if (isPlaying) {
                                event.target.mute();
                                if (isPlaying) {
                                    event.target.playVideo();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
            
            document.addEventListener('click', function() {
                watchPlayingState();
            });

        </script>
        """

        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

### Update

Following the supply of an answer below, I have modified the code further:

This new code gets the error "Type 'SmartReelView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'".

```
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var webView: WKWebView?

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView
        
        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.webView = webView
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }

    mutating func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if webView == nil {
            webView = uiView
            let embedHTML = """
            <style>
                .iframe-container iframe {
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="iframe-container">
                <div id="player"></div>
            </div>
            <script>
                var tag = document.createElement('script');
                tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                var player;
                var isPlaying = true;
                function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                    player = new YT.Player('player', {
                        width: '100%',
                        videoId: '\(link)',
                        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1 },
                        events: {
                            'onReady': function(event) {
                                event.target.mute();
                                event.target.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            
                function watchPlayingState() {
                    if (isPlaying) {
                        player.playVideo();
                    } else {
                        player.pauseVideo();
                    }
                }
            </script>
            """

            uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
            uiView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
        }

        let jsString = "isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false"); watchPlayingState();"
        webView?.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Swift code updates `isVideoPlaying`, but your JavaScript code does not detect the change. One standard way to communicate between Swift and JavaScript is using [`WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript). You could use this to run JavaScript code when your `isVideoPlaying` variable changes.

And each time you tap the clear view, your video reloads, which is not the behavior you want: you should avoid reloading the entire [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview). You can control the video's play and pause state using YouTube's JavaScript API.

So:

1. Update your `SmartReelView` to store a reference to `WKWebView`.
2. Add a `Coordinator` class to set up `WKNavigationDelegate`, as [in this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126986).
3. Use `evaluateJavaScript` to update the `isPlaying` JavaScript variable when the Swift `isVideoPlaying` variable changes.

```swift
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    // (existing code)
    
    // Point 1: Store a reference to WKWebView
    private var webView: WKWebView?

    // Point 2: Add a Coordinator class to set up WKNavigationDelegate
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView
        
        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        // WKNavigationDelegate method to capture the loaded WKWebView
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.webView = webView
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        
        // Set the navigation delegate to your Coordinator
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        // Only load the HTML when the webView is nil, prevents reloading
        if webView == nil {
            webView = uiView
            // Load HTML here (as in your existing code)
        }

        // Point 3: Use evaluateJavaScript to update isPlaying in JavaScript
        let jsString = "isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false"); watchPlayingState();"
        webView?.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

In your JavaScript:

- Remove the `var isPlaying = ...` line from the `onReady` function.
- make sure that `watchPlayingState()` uses the global `isPlaying` variable.

That way, your Swift code directly sets the JavaScript `isPlaying` variable and calls `watchPlayingState()` to either play or pause the video accordingly. It does not reload the video, but just uses the YouTube API to control it.

---

It is correct to make `webView` non-private if you plan to modify it in a nested class like `Coordinator`.

Since `UIViewRepresentable` expects non-mutating functions, it would be better to avoid the `mutating` keyword. Use a class instead of a struct for `SmartReelView` to avoid this. Classes are reference types and will not require the `mutating` keyword for their methods.

The error "`Type 'SmartReelView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'`" likely occurs because you have two versions of `SmartReelView` in your code. One of them (`new`) has the `makeCoordinator()` function while the other (`old`) does not. That can cause confusion for the Swift compiler. Remove the old version if it is not needed.

You could try:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

// (Same as above)

// Using a class instead of struct
class SmartReelView: NSObject, UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var webView: WKWebView?
    
    init(link: String, isPlaying: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.link = link
        self._isPlaying = isPlaying
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView
        
        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.webView = webView
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if webView == nil {
            webView = uiView
            // (Same HTML and JavaScript injection)
        }
        let jsString = "isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false"); watchPlayingState();"
        webView?.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}

// (Rest of your code)
```

I have converted `SmartReelView` to a class and retained the `makeCoordinator` function only in this class. I have also updated the initializer to take a `Binding` for `isPlaying`, which makes it compatible with how you use it in your `SingleVideoView`.

Comment: When I try your code I get 3 errors (I posted the revision above) so instead I found a workaround that basically uses a form of your solution. Now I am trying to figure out a way to auto play the video without it being muted. I was thinking instead of using the api function of .mute, I could find the mute button itself by id or query selection and clicking it.

Comment: So iframe and youtube policy does not allow auto play with unmuted. Instead I can turn auto play off and in my view have an onAppear block and a delay for a few seconds that toggles isPlaying. This will play the video unmuted after a couple seconds.

Comment: maybe you know how do the reverse of your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996573/how-to-communicate-from-embedded-html-to-swift-to-change-bool

Comment: @ahmed I have edited the answer to address your errors (before you edited your comments). I see you have found a workaround (and have upvoted it). It does not include a `Coordinator`, which was used in my edited answer to manage the WKWebView's delegate methods. The `Coordinator` might be useful if you need to handle additional web view events.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solution is actually better. It will probably help solve the question linked above your comment.

Comment: would you possible know the cause behind this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77056123/youtube-video-unresponsive-after-requesting-current-duration-swift

Answer (score 1):

To achieve an effect where the video auto plays when it appears and plays and pauses (without restarting video) without reloading when the screen is tapped you can use this code (the correct css has been added for a black background as well):

```
struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        
        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let jsString = "isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false"); watchPlayingState();"
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = true;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1 },
                    events: {
                        'onReady': function(event) {
                            event.target.mute();
                            event.target.playVideo();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```